# Парсинг с JSOUP. Игнорирование тэга

Tags: android, html, парсер, jsoup

Я спарсил новостную страничку, используя библиотеку JSOUP и получил новость:

```
    Element myNew = doc.select("div#news-id-ХХХ").first();
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    extractContent(myNew, result);
    Log.d("logs", "myNew-"+myNew.toString());
```

Логи показывают, что мой `Element` с новостью имеет следующий вид:

```
<div id="news-id-ХХХ" style="display:inline;">       
TEXT1   
<i>TEXT2</i>TEXT3           
<br>TEXT4
</div>
```

Я достаю текст рекурсивным перебором нодов:

```
private void extractContent(Node node, List<String> result) {
    if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        String text = ((TextNode) node).text().trim();
        if (!text.isEmpty()) result.add(text); // Добавляем только непустые тексты
    } 
}
```

На выходе я получаю следующее:

```
result.get(0) = TEXT1;  
result.get(1) = TEXT2;    
result.get(2) = TEXT3;    
result.get(3) = TEXT4;
```

А я хочу игнорировать тэг `<i>`, чтобы получилось следующее:

```
result.get(0) = TEXT1+TEXT2+TEXT3;    
result.get(1) = TEXT4;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать это.

Comment: Удаляйте ненужные теги в исходном коде страницы перед тем как парсить ее.

Comment: И как это сделать? :)

Comment: Элементарно :) https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace